# Android:ViewFlipper with onBackPressed

Tags: android, viewflipper

Ia m using ViewFlipper in my app, and to move inside the pages, I use a Button for next and capturing the onBackPressing to return back.

the behavior is the following:

1) I click on button and move to 2 page.
2) click back and code work
3) click again on the button next
4) click back and now wont work anymore

on the step 4, I can feel the vibration, so the event fire, but my viewflipper wont to go back.

Any suggestion?

Thank's

Comment: Some code would be most helpful is diagnosing this issue...

Comment: Sorry, problem solved (bug found), if you set the focus of an editText on the second page, then the back button don't work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void onBackPressed() {


        if (flipView.getDisplayedChild() == 1) {
            flipView.setDisplayedChild(0);

        } else if (flipView.getDisplayedChild() == 0) {
            flipView.setDisplayedChild(1);
        }

    }
```

This works perfectly for me. Change onBackPressed to what ever method is calling the back button.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add something to the other answer.

Let's say we have only two views that we are flipping through, doing:

```
  public void onBackPressed() {

    if (mViewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == 1) {
        mViewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(0);
     } else if (mViewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == 0) {
        flipView.setDisplayedChild(1);
    }
}
```

isn't enough. As a matter of fact, it creates another problem for you.
If the view is in 0 (the first), and you then press the back button, NOTHING happens. The activity doesn't exit. This is because you haven't called `super.onBackPressed()`. Now, adding `super.onBackPressed()` to the code above also creates another problem. When you flip from 1 (the second view) it goes to the first view (0) and then exits the activity, which is wrong if not for anything but for the weird animation of skipping a view while transitioning from one activity to another.

The best way to implement `onBackPressed()` for your activity containing a `ViewFlipper` is this:

```
  public void onBackPressed() {
    int displayedChildId = mViewFlipper.getDisplayedChild(); //get current view's number
    if (displayedChildId > 0) { //if this number is greater than 0(let's say 5)
        mViewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(displayedChildId - 1);//We then go down that number by 1. That is 5 - 1, which is 4. This happens until displayedChildId isn't greater than 0 anymore, which is then the first view. if we press back from here, we exit the activity.
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

I hope this makes sense